# Type conditional not working as expected using conditional types based on prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, conditional-types

## Conditional types based on prop

I have this issue of multiple types that are dependent on single prop (in a React component). These types can not be mixed, but that would never be the case because of their shared dependencies on the same prop. However typescript can not infer the generic types based on the prop. Below is a code example (React components is simplified to pure javascript functions):

```js
type AsType = "input" | "select"

type ForwardedRef<T extends HTMLElement> = (instance: T) => void

type RefType<T extends AsType> = T extends "input"
  ? ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>
  : T extends "select"
  ? ForwardedRef<HTMLSelectElement>
  : never

type PropsType<T extends AsType>  = {
    className?: string
    as?: T
}

function Select({ forwardedRef }: { forwardedRef: ForwardedRef<HTMLSelectElement> }) {
    console.log("Select", forwardedRef)
}

function Input({ forwardedRef }: { forwardedRef: ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement> }) {
    console.log("Input", forwardedRef)
}

function test<T extends AsType = "input">(props: PropsType<T>, forwardedRef: RefType<T>) {
    if (props.as === "input") {
        // Typescript error: Type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement> | ForwardedRef<HTMLSelectElement>' is not assignable to type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>'.
        return Input({ forwardedRef }) 
    } else {
        // Typescript error: Type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement> | ForwardedRef<HTMLSelectElement>' is not assignable to type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>'.
        return Select({ forwardedRef }) 
    }
}
```

*Code is also on this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggzgFXNAvFARASwHZgK7DpQA+GcEANhAMaEBQdokUAYgPYBOA7gIYcAmEfgCUIAMwA8CKBAAewCNn5woACQQBZADIBRKgFtFwAHxQ0AChxxgPbNQgAuKAgCUZ0wDc2mfgybRRMSRIKRl5RWVYRGRTNGk5BSUVLFwCdDooKAB+Vk5eASFAiXVtAElU4D0IQ2wTDKgnePCkskoaekyc9m4+QRFxYs0tAGU22iqausynbAgPCA4-ZCgABQ42MGiQpsTI+GCIUzMoAG96zOoKHjg4ADkeQyynaw4cAHNzqGun5zoAXwYYjwdmAmDY2CgoyotHMJygYjyvUK4igfyccIRPQK-TETm6+T6RRKIzGlQMRlMfzcZ0yF3BcDYVAAdBQ2G9zOgoe10AAaeGI7GBFz-QHA2hgiHlfDAWH8rGElFo05ygnI3G5eVqwZlCoTCmo6mfaj0xkQFlsjlStJ8zGqnHCgF0IEgiVQBTWUIJCIqfbLNApaXoYzmMDrTZONYbLYQKTGG0ChXqwIHWOG2lQTBiKAhsNwJnXMwof04QNp9O0gD0FecyDg1FeYGAMg46w4jWWAHJ8UicdqtFaydV9aRu4KBsSueNybVjB2MypsGwm9c4Jg3tgeAAjKhuthuzujxN9gd6mcdpmfdMcCDAPAcSUVWW2nuBA1QT5-GQUcinS+V6sHHWDZNgsrbtswXYJlqxIntOJgkBqdpEkMk6DpMs7zlAi7Ljca4btu0DAHu-hQJBmq9jBupwbOF7lrS163vekKkk+UE4m+H4MH8QA*).

It works if I write `Select({ ref: ref as ForwardedRef<"select"> })` but I would very much prefer not to do that, especially because in my real life example do I have more props then only the ref (including handlers like `onCreate`, `onBlur` that also dependents on a HTMLElement subtype).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wyo86N) work for you? I had to change the expected arguments however this way it works and if it works for you, I will write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame thank you very much! It is very close to a solution, I would love to understand how you came to that, and why it is that typescript understands that differently? However I need the props, and ref to be two different arguments (as that's how React.forwardRef passes the argument), and it seems like typescript infers the type differently when it's inside a object as opposed to an array of args.

Comment: With the array approach, typescript can't guarantee that if the first element obeys some condition, the second obeys as well. That's why we are limited in doing it with an array. As an alternative, you can create a type guard for select props and input props that will only check the `props.as`, however, I would avoid doing this because we are going to check only `props.as === 'input'`. If that's fine for you I can write up an answer

Comment: @wonderflame I'm not 100 % sure how that would work, but yes it would be great if you would write a answer using multiple args, instead of a single object arg. And thank you again!

Comment: can you check [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N5ADVN)?